# how to fetch data stored in sqlite3 database and assign it to the variables in tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, integer

In the code below I saved value1 and value2 to the sqlite3 database and txt_ in folder named data.
What I am trying to achieve here is that when I rerun the programme and open the file, txt_ file should be open in the text area with the lines I added when I saved it. And when I click add button, value1 and value2 should be updated and newly created line should be in the next line.
Let me know if my method is correct, if not then please tell me the better one.

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')

var_e = StringVar(None)
def create_my_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database=r'my db.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "myLogs"
                (
                    "int_value" INTEGER,
                    "float_value" REAL
                )
                """)
    conn.commit()
create_my_db()

def add_lbl():
    global value1, value2
    value1 += 1
    value2 += 1
    sample = f'This is line {value1} which has value of {value2}\n'
    txt_.insert(END, sample)

def save():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database=r'my db.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO myLogs VALUES (?,?)""",
                (
                    value1,
                    value2
                )
                )
    conn.commit()

    # labels to check if the values are stored in the database
    values_lbl.config(text=f'value 1 is [ {value1} ] & value 2 is [ {value2} ]')

def save_txt():
    file_txt = open(f'data/{value1}.txt', 'w')
    file_txt.write(txt_.get(1.0, END))
    file_txt.close()
    messagebox.showinfo('SAVED', 'Data saved to the database.')

def open_():
    for txt_file in os.listdir("data/"):
        if txt_file.split('.')[0] == f'{var_e.get()}':
            file_ = open(f"data/{txt_file}", "r")
            for i in file_:
                txt_.insert(END, i)
            file_.close()

value1 = 0
value2 = 0.9

values_lbl = Label(root, text=f'value 1 is [ {value1} ] & value 2 is [ {value2} ]')
values_lbl.pack()

btn_frame = Frame(root)
btn_frame.pack()

btn_add = Button(btn_frame, text='Add', command=add_lbl)
btn_add.pack(side=LEFT)

e = Entry(btn_frame, textvariable=var_e)
e.pack(side=LEFT)

btn_open = Button(btn_frame, text='Open', command=open_)
btn_save = Button(btn_frame, text='Save', command=lambda:[save(), save_txt()])
btn_open.pack(side=LEFT)
btn_save.pack(side=LEFT)

txt_ = Text(root)
txt_.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working? What does the program do when you run it?

Comment: I don't know how to update value1 and value2 when I rerun the programme. I've attached the image, where I added three lines and then saved it. Then I rerun the programme and open the file. But  value1 and value2 are reset to 0 and 0.9 respectively.
The 4th line should be "This is the line 4 which has value of 4.9"

Comment: You need to update `value1` and `value2` inside `open_()`.

Comment: @acw1668, yeh you are right, but I don't know how.
Can you please show me?

Comment: I wonder why you don't know how as you have already done similar stuff inside `add_lbl()`.

Comment: @acw1668, in `add_lbl()` I just increment the `value1` and `value2` by 1 which was easy.
while in case of `open_()` I don't know how to get the `int_value` and `float_value` from the database and assign them to the variable `value1` and `value2` respectively.

Comment: You can use the following SQL: `SELECT MAX(int_value), MAX(float_vaue) FROM myLogs` to update `value1` and `value2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I posted this question I didn't know how to run the query to update value1 and value2, that's why I didn't mention the query in `open_()` function. Now I came to know how that query should have been done. So in the below code I added the query to `open_()` function. Now the complete programme runs fine.

```
def open_():
    global value1, value2
    txt_.delete(1.0, END)
    for txt_file in os.listdir("data/"):
        if txt_file.split('.')[0] == f'{var_e.get()}':
            file_ = open(f"data/{txt_file}", "r")
            for i in file_:
                txt_.insert(END, i)
            file_.close()

    conn = sqlite3.connect(database=r'my db.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM myLogs WHERE int_value=?""", (var_e.get(),))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR", 'Invalid input.')
    else:
        value1 = row[0]
        value2 = row[1]
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).